# Match all text between \w: placeholders

Tags: python, regex

I need to match text between undefined `\w:` patterns (so `n: text`, `foo: text` and `n: text foo: more text`, more examples in the test script below).

To do this, I'm using python's `finditer` and a regex, but I can't capture more multiple words between placeholders.  How can I adjust either the regex, or the `finditer` method to do what I want?

```py
import re

def test_query_parse_regex(query, expected_result):
    result = {}

    # perform the matching here, this needs to change
    r = r"([\w-]+):\s?([\w-]*)"
    matches = re.finditer(r, query)

    for match in matches:
        # eg 'n'
        operator = match.group(1).strip()
        # eg 'text'
        operator_value = match.group(2).strip()

    # build a dict for comparison
    result[operator] = operator_value
    if result == expected_result:
        print(f"PASS: {query}")
    else:
        print(f"FAIL: {query}")
        print(f"  Expected: {expected_result}")
        print(f"  Got     : {result}")


checks = [
    # Query, expected
    ("n: tom", {"n": "tom"}),
    ("n: tom preston", {"n": "tom preston"}),
    ("n: tom l: london", {"n": "tom", "l": "london"}),
    ("n: tom preston l: london derry", {"n": "tom preston", "l": "london derry"}),
]

for check in checks:
    test_query_parse_regex(*check)
```

Note. I've tried a positive look ahead but can't make that work either: `r"([\w-]+):\s?([\w-]*)(?=\w:)"`

Comment: Try `r = r"([\w-]+):\s*(.*?)(?=[\w-]+:|\Z)"` (and `re.finditer(r, query, re.DOTALL)` if your strings can have line breaks).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very nice!  If you write that up you have the points- I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
r = r"([\w-]+):\s*(.*?)(?=[\w-]+:|$)"
r = r"([\w-]+):\s*(.*?)(?=[\w-]+:|\Z)"
```

Note that if your strings can have line breaks you will need to also amend the `re.finditer` part to

```py
re.finditer(r, query, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ACvLLq/1). Prefer the version with `\Z` if you use the `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` option since `\Z` always matches the very end of string.

*Details*:

- `([\w-]+)` - Group 1: one or more word or hyphen chars
- `:\s*` - a colon and any zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than line break chars (if `re.DOTALL` is not used) as few as possible
- `(?=[\w-]+:|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more word or hyphen chars followed with a colon, or end of string, immediately to the right of the current location.